# Android XML file doesn't show suggestions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

My android studio layout .xml file doesn't show suggestions. I have tried to invalidate cache and restart but that didn't work for me. Can anyone help me to solve this problem because it's difficult to design xml without any suggestions.

Comment: post your xml file and also console error log

Comment: Is it only xml, or java as well? If so, check if you didn't turn on power saving mode occasionally

Comment: Check your AppTheme and Gradle

Comment: my power saving mode is off...and it only happens in xml not in java file

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart
```

Or try this **untick** the  :

```
"File -> Power Save Mode" in Android Studio
```

Comment: I have already done this...and my power save mode is already uncheck..please suggest me another solution

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .idea folder and .iml files from the project and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible ways that you should try.

1. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Select Invalidate and Restart
2. Close the android studio. Navigate to your android studio installation directory, i.e

   C:/.AndroidStudio3.6/system

and DELETE THE CACHES FOLDER.
Then start Android Studio again. Done.

I am using android studio 3.6.

3. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run. Unchecked the box next to Restart activity on code changes. Hope it will resolve the issue.